# merge two number into varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

How can I merge two numbers into varchar in sql function?

The function output is varchar(40) and the two numbers are parameters of function.

I found this: *siteowner := concat(eov_y, eov_x);* but it doesn't work well.

siteowner is the output. I am using Oracle 10g.

for examlpe eov_y = 234543 and eov_x = 675654 and the output will be siteowner = 234543 / 675654.

Comment: Can you explain *what* doesn't work "well"?

Comment: I am using ORACLE 10g and got this error message: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small @mabi

Comment: And what *should* be stored when both outputs combined exceed 40 chars? `eov_y` and fill up what's left with `eov_x`?

Comment: yes @mabi, and that would be great if there is a / separate between eov_y and eov_x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be more efficient ways to do this but this should work

```
LEFT(CAST(@eov_y AS varchar) + CAST(@eov_x AS varchar), 40)
```

For clarity here is an example of how this could be used

```
CREATE FUNCTION mergeNumbers 
(
    @eov_y INT,
    @eov_x INT
)
RETURNS varchar(40)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN LEFT(CAST(@eov_y AS varchar) + CAST(@eov_x AS varchar), 40);
END
```

Which can be called with

```
SELECT dbo.mergeNumbers(11244,456);
```

*This assumes SQL Server*

As per comments, I don't have an Oracle db to try this but it should be about right

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mergeNumbers (eov_y NUMBER, eov_x NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR IS
   siteowner VARCHAR(40);
BEGIN
   siteowner := SUBSTR(CAST(@eov_y AS VARCHAR) + CAST(@eov_x AS VARCHAR), 40);     
   RETURN siteowner;
END;
```

Comment: do you mean siteowner := LEFT(CAST(@eov_y AS varchar) + CAST(@eov_x AS varchar), 40); ? @Jonathan

Comment: Assuming siteowner is your return value, then it would be `SELECT @siteowner = LEFT(CAST(@eov_y AS varchar) + CAST(@eov_x AS varchar), 40); RETURN @siteowner`

Comment: do you have solution for oracle 10g?

Comment: Please see my revised answer. I am not proficient in Oracle but hopefully this works.

Comment: I removed the '@' before 'eov_y' and 'eov_x' in begin part and it compiled and run this: <i> SELECT mergenumbers(2,4) from dual; </i> and the result is NULL